# div remains visible after the page reloads

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have languages link on my website when I load my home page the middle content div for the main page is visible by default and some other divs for the middle portion are also loaded but they are hidden. When a user click on a link(other than languages link) on home page the content div for that link appears and the default one hides so clicking on the link only show and hide the content divs not reloading the page. but when a div with some content is visible and i click the language link it reloads the page which is fine but I want the div to be visible that was visible before the reload and currently when it reloads the page it makes the main div visible 
My view code is

```
************** Main Div***************

<div id="main-content">
<div id="left-ad">
    <img  style="margin-bottom:2px" src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/left-ad.jpg" height="270px" alt="Ad" />
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="menu">                    
        <ul id="language_selector">
            <?php foreach ($languages as $lang) { ?> 
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name']?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/default/version01/images/country_<?php echo $lang['language_name'] ?>.png" width="27" height="18" border="0" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?> 
        </ul>                       
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $variables_data[1]['value'] ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $variables_data[2]['value'] ?></p>
    <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>             
<div id="download">
    <div id="download_arrow">
        <img id="download_arrow" src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/download_arrow.png" alt="Free Download" height="36" width="43" />
    </div>
    <div id="download_button">
        <img id="download_button" src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/download_button.png" alt="Free Download" height="60" width="123" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

```
***************Hidden divs********************

<?php foreach ($titles_data as $title) { ?>
<div style="display:none; margin: 0 10px; font-size:12px;" id="content_<?php echo $title['idtitles'] ?>">
    <div id="left-ad">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/download?file=<?php echo $title['pdf_path'] ?>" class='download_dialog'>
            <img  style="margin-bottom:2px" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>import/<?php echo $title['image_path'] ?>" height="270px" alt="Ad" />
        </a><br />
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/download?file=<?php echo $title['pdf_path'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/download_button2.png"/></a> 
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">                    
            <ul id="language_selector">
                <?php foreach ($languages as $lang) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>/<?php echo $lang['language_name']?>" onclick="activate('content_<?php echo $title['idtitles'] ?>')">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/default/version01/images/country_<?php echo $lang['language_name'] ?>.png" width="27" height="18" border="0" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>                       
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $title['title'] ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $title['description'] ?></p>
        <div style="clear:right;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>             
    <div id="download">
        <div id="download_arrow">
            <img id="download_arrow" src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/download_arrow.png" alt="Free Download" height="36" width="43" />
        </div>
        <div id="download_button">
            <img id="download_button" src="<?php echo $template_data['images_path'] ?>/download_button.png" alt="Free Download" height="60" width="123" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Some users suggested to use jquery cookie plugin but I dont know how to use it with codeigniter.

Any good source of help ?

or any other alternative ?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: As this is the fifth related question you have asked in the building of this code, perhaps it would be good to accept an answer for one of the previous questions, or post the answer/update your question with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a session variable stored in as a cookie or create a hash link to open the correct div when the page refreshes.

You could try:

- jQuery Cookie Plugin - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
- jQuery Hashchange Event Plugin - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is to set a cookie with JavaScript. Then when rendering the page read that cookie to hide the main div.

Comment: SteveO's answer above is good.  The jQuery cookie plugin will be handy, along with a simple bit of PHP code such as if (isset($_COOKIE['yourcookiename'])) {

Comment: Should I send the div id to a jquery function onclick event of the link and then set it as a cookie there ? but how can I get cookie value if it is set in a script ? can you plz provide me some sudo code with the refrence to my code given ... Thanks

Comment: Hi faryal. That sounds a bit complex. While jquery is useful you can do everything here with php without much difficulty. Just read up on handling cookies with php before you plan out your solution.

Comment: Hey I read about cookies but I am confused to use it in MVC structure... The point is I need to click on a link it should have href which redirect it to home page and its not keeping the current div visible but replaces it with the home page div

Comment: I tried cookies but i think its the solution to my problem :(