# Need to set the value of the select box to the selected value and retrieve it each time when you visit the page

Tags: jquery, jsp, tags

```
<form>
    <b>Select the type </b>
    <select name="navigate"
        onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].selected=true;window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option 
            value="/">Select
        </option>           
        <option
            value="${url}&_eventId=candidateSelectionList&candidateSelection=digital">
            <fmt:message
                key="DAL" />
        </option>
        <option
            value="${url}&_eventId=candidateSelectionList&candidateSelection=copy">
            <fmt:message
                key="Copy" />
        </option>
        <option
            value="${url}&_eventId=candidateSelectionList&candidateSelection=form">
            <fmt:message
                key="Form" />
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

i have this Jsp tag file, which is used for a dropdown,the page to display is dependant upon the url posted. My problem is it always defaults back to "Select". 
Even if i select one item from the dropdown, **it will forward me to the correct page, but the dropdown goes back to select.** i want it to **set to the value selected** and when i return back after doing somehting else, it should still give me the selected one instead of "select".
i guess i may need to put in session or something right
?

Comment: <c:out value="${candidateSelection}"></c:out> I could get the selected dropdown from the flow scope. now the question is how to show the correct option depending upon the {candidateSelection} and fire the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie or hashchange event would be best. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824417/1158469

Comment: hashchange is supported natively in IE8 and up, and in every other current browser.

Comment: Why can't you add the plugin? Could you expand on your problem?